# How to use variable within component inside function in react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, function, react-native, mobile

I'm retrieving some data from a realtime database (firebase), however, when I try to check the value of 'levels' outside of the database reference call, I get an undefined value, despite it working within the reference.

Is there a way to allow access to the variable 'levels' inside the react-native components?

I have seen some examples online that use this.setState in order to achieve this, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this within a function.

```
function LevelsScreen() {
    const reference = database()
    .ref()
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      //get Levels from db
      let levels = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          levels.push(child.key);
      })
      console.log(levels);
  
  });
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.categories}>
        {/* Horizontal Scrollbox for Main Categories */}
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View>

            {/* This function should call LevelCard to return the components with the proper titles*/}
            {levels.map(element => {
                return (<LevelCard
                level={element}/>)
                })
            }

          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use *state* to let react know what to render.
2. When the data is fetched from the database, we update the state.
3. Updating the state triggers re-render in React, which says React to render something new in the screen.
4. Then, you could show to the user your new state.

```
function LevelsScreen() {
  // use state so that the react can know when the update the screen.
  const [levels, setLevels] = React.useState(null);

  // upon the component mount, we call the database.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    database()
      .ref()
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        //get Levels from db
        const levels = snapshot.map((child) => child.key);
        // update the state so react knows to re-render the component
        setLevels(levels);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.categories}>
      {/* Horizontal Scrollbox for Main Categories */}
      {levels ? (
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View>
            {/* This function should call LevelCard to return the components with the proper titles*/}
            {levels.map((element) => {
              return <LevelCard level={element} />;
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      ) : (
        {/* show spinner when the levels is not got from the server */}
        <ActivityIndicator />
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you can use Promises for such.

```
function LevelsFunction() {
    return Promise(resolve=> {
    database()
    .ref()
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
    const levels = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      levels.push(child.key);
    })
    console.log(levels);
    resolve(levels)
});
```

Now access the LevelsFunction from anywhere you want with either using async/await or then.

Ex:

```
componentDidMount(){
    const levels = LevelsFunction().then(res => res);
    console.log(levels);
}
```

or

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const levels = await LevelsFunction();
    console.log(levels);
}
```

I strongly recommend you **NOT** to use this inside the class render function.